# Rasterizing lines significantly slower than polygons

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I'm using GSHHG data to create land masks. Rasterizing the original polygons with GDAL_rasterize (via Python) is very quick. However, when I convert the polygons to lines and rasterize *that*, the process is much slower: seconds for the polygons vs minutes for lines.

Is there a particular reason for this e.g. some optimization I'm missing?

*(in case you're wondering why I'm rasterizing the lines, it's to get a raster showing only cells with coastline in them)*

Comment: I believe that optimization should be done in the source code https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/apps/gdal_rasterize_bin.cpp and especially https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/alg/gdalrasterize.cpp. Difference seconds vs. minutes makes me feel that there really is something to optimize. Can you provide test data?